# Ajax loader on file upload action

Tags: ajax, file-upload, symfony1

I would like to configure some kind of ajax loader to an action that executes a file upload. Once the file is quite large (Excel with more than 2000 rows), it takes sometime to be processed and its quite unpleasant to the user, wait with no other feedback than the displayed by the browser.

For me, the ideal solution, would be a blocking popup, displaying a message "Processing the file..." (or something like that), to prevent users to upload another file in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

Well... I've got something like this in place on a Symfony app although this doesn't really relate to Symfony:

**TEMPLATE:**

```
<input type="submit" class="jq-upload" value="Upload" /> // submit button
<div class="jq-loader"></div> // empty div for a loader image
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $(".jq-upload").click(function() {
     $(".jq-loader").addClass("jq-load-icon");
  });
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.jq-load-icon {width: 16px; height: 16px; background: url('../images/loader.gif') no-repeat;}
```

So, basically the click on upload button adds a class to the empty div next to it, which has an animated gif as a background image. In this case, it's a typical loading icon.

That should give you enough to create a popup or adjust it to your needs.